# can't explain NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In the following code, i have a method to get a `Vector` of persons with the same zodiac sign. `persoane` is a `Vector<Persoana>`. I keep getting a `NullPointerException` at the if condition (`persoane` is definetly not null). I am unable to see why. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public Vector<Persoana> cautaDupaZodie(String zodie)
{
    Vector<Persoana> rezultat= new Vector<Persoana>();

    for(int i=0; i<persoane.size(); i++)
    {
        if(persoane.get(i).getData().getZodie().equals(zodie)) //the exception occurs here
        {
            rezultat.add(persoane.get(i));
        }

    }

    return rezultat;
}
```

Comment: No offense, but any API methods (i.e. any that are public) should have standardized English names to be understandable to a broader audience of programmers.

Comment: Breaking up the if statement and printing intermediate results will help you to find out which part is null.

Comment: @Michael: according to what standard? And who says that this is part of some API? It may very well be code from a in-house project (or even some homework).

Comment: There isn't a standard... it's just easier to follow code where the words make sense.  When you use nonsensical words, it can be difficult to follow.  And if I were someone asking for help, I would want my code to be very readable to the people I"m asking.

Comment: Where is persoane coming from?   Can we assume that it's a class member?

Comment: @David: calling words in a language that you don't understand "nonsensical" points at a very narrow world view. And for this problem the domain knowledge isn't relevant. It would be equally hard to understand if the words where jargon from some scientific area. Would you insist that those words be replace with "everyday words" as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NullPointerException` occurs, when you try to call a method on an `Object` that is `null`.

This means that one of the following returns `null`:

- `get(i)`
- `getData()`
- `getZodie()`

Add them one by one to find out what actually is causing your exception.

Comment: Thank you, apparently i didn't make sure that getData() always returns a not null value.

Answer (score 2):

```
persoane.get(i).getData().getZodie()
```

break that down into several lines to see where the NPE occurs.

Also, consider using the for-each loop.

```
for (Persoana persoana: rezultat){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getData()` or `getZodie()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You may add some "tracing" code:

```
public Vector<Persoana> cautaDupaZodie(String zodie)
{
    Vector<Persoana> rezultat= new Vector<Persoana>();

    for(int i=0; i<persoane.size(); i++)
    {
        System.err.println(persoane.get(i));
        System.err.println(persoane.get(i).getData());
        System.err.println(persoane.get(i).getData().getZodie());
        if(persoane.get(i).getData().getZodie().equals(zodie)) //the exception occurs here
        {
            rezultat.add(persoane.get(i));
        }

    }

    return rezultat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be any of the following:

- `persoane` contains a `null` at any index
- Any of the elements of `persoane` returns `null` for `getData()`
- Any of the `getData()` results retruns `null` for `getZodie()`

To investigate further, you'd best break up that chain of methods and add a conditional breakpoint. Additionally, rethink your design - this kind of "method operating on deeply nested, behaviourless data structure" is bad for this and other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use `List<Person>` if possible. Then, I recommend breaking the method chain to a smaller steps to see which exact step is failing.

```
public List<Person> searchZodiac(String zodiac) {
    assert zodiac != null; // if it fails here, zodiac == null

    List<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();

    for (Person p : persons) {
        Data d = p.getData();      // if it fails here, p == null
        String z = d.getZodiac();  // if it fails here, d == null
        if (z.equals(zodiac)) {    // if it fails here, z == null
           result.add(p);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(persoane.get(i).getData().getZodie().equals(zodie))
```

break the above line into several parts.Here getData must be returning null so you are getting NullPointerException